# Threads permanently blocking on barrier

Tags: c, pthreads, barrier, pthread-barriers

I'm working on an assignment which involves the use of various thread synchronizing mechanisms, but the only one that's giving me a headache is pthread_barrier_t.

The idea is to implement the barrier as a checkpoint for a few threads, but they are blocking permanently.

I checked a few answers here and my implementation seems correct, even compiled and ran [this simple one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28663622/understanding-posix-barrier-mechanism) without any issues.

**cpu.c** (contains the main thread):

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include "../include/cpu.h"
#include "../include/units.h"

pthread_barrier_t barrier;

void cpu_boot() {
  pthread_barrier_init(&barrier, NULL, 2));
}

void *cpu_thread() {
  pthread_t unit1_thread;
  pthread_t unit2_thread;
  pthread_create(&unit1_thread, NULL, &unit1_func, NULL);
  pthread_create(&unit2_thread, NULL, &unit2_func, NULL);

  (...)

  pthread_join(unit1_thread, NULL);
  pthread_join(unit2_thread, NULL);

  pthread_exit(0);
}
```

**units.c** (contains the other threads' functions):

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include "../include/units.h"
#include "../include/cpu.h"

void *unitN_func() {

  (...)

  pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier);
  pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Some notes:

- Both files I'm referencing have their own header file
- I *carefully* removed some pieces of the code to make it shorter
- Function bodies are mostly empty anyway, I'm waiting for the barrier to work
- Error checks were also removed to keep the code short (no errors on execution)
- barrier count reflects the removal of a few threads
- barrier is externed on cpu.h

Thanks!

Comment: Do you ever call `cpu_boot()`? If not, your barrier is never initialized and you most likely are invoking undefined behavior as a result. You should probably amend the code you've posted to make it a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What you have posted right now sort of shows some structure, but it's not very useful beyond that...